# How to access both EPC , Tagid and USER memory banks in RFID tag (Chainway C72)

Tags: rfid

We are developing an application using chainway C72 device (Android 11). We have to read multiple tags simultaneously and for each tag, we have to get EPC, Tag ID and one particular word from EPC (64 to 1 word - DataWord). We managed to get all data but tagID, EPC and the data word are not getting properly when multiple tags are in range. It is giving epc of one tag, tag id of another one and Data word of another one tag. Is there any method to read all three parameters together for a particular tag?
We are using the UHFReadData function to get the result.